# How to get notified when someone commented on my site using facebook commenting system?

Tags: php, html

Having used the [Facebook commenting plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) on my site, I want to get notified when someone commented on my site

They have provide how to get notified, but I don't understand how to use it!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Get notified via my fb profile or however..! i jst want to get notified...

Comment: With which part of the linked documentation are you having trouble?

Comment: I dnt have any troble...commenting system is working..i just want to get notified when someone commented..

Comment: "You can subscribe to the '`comment.create`' and '`comment.remove`' events through [`FB.Event.subscribe`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)." *Ibid.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not programmatical question, but I'll answer it. NO, it's NOT possible by their default options.

You can use ther [JsSdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)

or you can just see these comments on your site.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
   // send ajax request to your server which will notify you about new comment
});
```

Comment: But tell have told it is possible..[link]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Why are you asking here then. edited ?

Comment: i dont know how to do it! I'm new to here..plz help me..

Comment: @NaviGamage: see my code in answer